# Most likely route to hostile domain take-over?

Tags: dnssec

Say a citizen-run journalist site is a target of a hostile government.  The site is hosted over HTTPS in a different country, outside the government's reach. However,  the site domain name is within the country's top level domain.

I think the most likely route for the hostile government is to take over the DNS record, [intercept ACME](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/273682/can-a-powerful-adversary-trick-acme-to-generate-a-certificate) and simply replace the infrastructure with their own, without the users necessarily noticing, after which slow-paced censorship can start taking place.

What is the most likely sequence of steps the hostile government will perform to take over the DNS record?

- no DNSSEC enabled
- DNSSEC enabled

Does the usage of DNSSEC make the take-over easier or more difficult?

Comment: replacing the infrastructure and changing content is probably the least likely path.  (too much work for them)  If they don't like a particular news outlet, they'd just ban it and make sure only their own approved sources are available inside their country.

Comment: valid point, but the question is about this specific case that _can_ arise in practice - the question really is about the technical aspects of domain takeover

Comment: If the hostile government controls the TLD of the domain name, then the hostile government can take-over the domain, and point the domain name to their own DNS servers.  At that point, they can get a valid certificate for the domain (using ACME or plain old domain validation), and host whatever content they want on a web server at that domain.  DNSSEC won't help in this scenario.  See https://moxie.org/2011/04/11/ssl-and-the-future-of-authenticity.html for some interesting reading on this subject.

Comment: Yeah, if DNSSEC is used, sounds like it'd be necessary to regenerate some keys down the tree.